# Problem with wi-fi

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, wifi-hardware-switch

I have a problem with The wi-fi, I was use windows and I have converted to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS "last version", but when I connecting to internet with wi-fi, the Connection keeping stopping every 2~5 minutes, but when I connecting with normal cable or usb , the Connection is working normal, I tried with most of versions, all of that's have a same problem with the wi-fi, I like Ubuntu so much but this problem make my experience with The great OS is less comfortable, so really I need to help, I hope to fix this problem, and sorry for my poor English it's not my native language .

Comment: which wifi card is in the computer?

Comment: product: RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

Comment: anyone gonna help me ??